# How to give one function the scope of another without nested functions in C?

Tags: python, c, matlab, function, nested

In Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def f1(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

x = 5;
y = 6;
z = 7;

fm = lambda m: f1(m,x,y,z)
print fm(4)
```

In Matlab:

```
function [retval] = f1(a, b, c, d)
    retval = a + b + c + d;

x = 5;
y = 6;
z = 7;

fm = @(m) f1(m,x,y,z);
fm(4)
```

I know there are no nested functions in C without using the gcc extension. How do I get the same functionality in C as using nested functions? How do I declare variables and use them as constants in another function like in the examples?

Comment: By declaring them as global static variables? Or by passing them as arguments.

Comment: I thought global variables were bad. It would work, but is it really the best way?

Comment: If your program consists of modules, putting your previously nested functions in one module, with static declarations for shared variables, would prevent them becoming available to other sections of your code.

Comment: @user1801359 : I used an answer because I needed some code formatting. To make a long story short: your question doesn't make sense as is, so please post a better example of what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like a "nested function" in your Python example - only an anonymous function, which could be replaced by a named one. FWIW your Python snippet is easy to rewrite in C:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int f1(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}

int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int z = 7;

int fm(int m) {
    return f1(m, x, y, z);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d\n", fm(4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All the answers including this one use global variables. Is this one situation where the solution is to use them?

Comment: @user1801359: your Python snippet uses globals too. Ok, Python's "global" variables are really "module globals", but in the above code it doesn't make any difference. As I commented: what's your _real_ question ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with a preprocessor macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Global variables?
int x = 5, y= 6, z = 7;

int f1( int a, int b, int c, int d )
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}

#define fm(m) f1((m), x, y, z)

int main()
{
    fprintf( stdout, "%d\n", f1( 4, x, y, z ) );
    fprintf( stdout, "%d\n", fm( 4 ) );
}
```

Or if you could use C++:

```
#include <iostream>

// Global variables?
int x = 5, y= 6, z = 7;

int f1( int a, int b, int c, int d )
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}

// Alternative is using default arguments (much cleaner too)
int easy( int a, int b = 5, int c = 6, int d = 7 )
{
    return a + b + c + d;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << f1( 4, x, y, z ) << std::endl;
    auto fm = [](int m)->int { return f1( m, x, y, z ); };  // Use lambda function
    std::cout << fm( 4 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << easy( 4 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I need a solution in C, not C++. The lambda function is not in C, right?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis:   c !=  c++

Comment: Weather Vane, I did not notice C tag.  It was an oversight.
Yeah, no duh, @bruno desthuilliers.  Relax; you'll live longer.